# Running a http call every two mins

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have a service with the function:

```
fetchChatCirclesFromServer(): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post(
      this.apiurl + '/chat-circle/getChatCircles',
      {user: {loc: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng}}},
      {headers: this.headers}
    )
  }
```

I am subscribing to this Observable in the component like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.chatCircleService.fetchChatCirclesFromServer()
  .subscribe(resp => {
    this.chatCircles = resp.json().chatCircle
    this.chatCircleService.joinChatCircle(this.chatCircles[0].id)
  })
}
```

How can I transform the fetchChatCirclesFromServer() function so that it calls the http.post emits the response back to the component every 2 mins?
I have tried Observable.interval().timeInterval() solution posted on similar questions but that doesn't even compile in my case. 
Thanks

Comment: Why it does not compile? What errors are you getting? What was the implementation of the time interval solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
fetchChatCirclesFromServer(): Observable<Response> {
    return Rx.Observable.interval(120000).flatMap(() => {
        return this.http.post(
            this.apiurl + '/chat-circle/getChatCircles',
            {user: {loc: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng}}},
            {headers: this.headers}
        )
    });
}
```

Comment: This is compiling, but on chrome console its throwing error that Observable.interval is not a function, even after importing 'rxjs/observable/interval'. Is there something else I have to import?

Answer (score 1):

```
ngOnInit() {
  Observable.timer(0, 120000)  // starting immediately, calling every 120seconds (or 2 minutes)
    .switchMap(() => this.chatCircleService.fetchChatCirclesFromServer())  // then switch to the request-stream from the service
    .subscribe(resp => {
        this.chatCircles = resp.json().chatCircle
        this.chatCircleService.joinChatCircle(this.chatCircles[0].id)
      })
}
```

**Note 1**: Don't forget to close the subscription in case your components is removed at any point during the application-runtime.

**Note 2**: `.interval(n: number)` won't emit immediately, but only after the first interval, in this case this would be after 2 minutes, whereas with `timer(initialDelay, interval)` you can define a custom initial delay, which you could set to 0.

Comment: This is compiling properly, however chrome console is throwing up error saying timer is not a function of observable, even after importing { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable' and 'rxjs/observable/timer'. Is there something else I need to import?

Comment: `import "rxjs/add/observable/timer";`